# How to set an action to primefaces keyboard's enter button

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am new to JSF and PrimeFaces. I wish to use on-screen keyboard in my login page for my JSF project and I found primefaces keyboard. When I press the enter button in the primefaces keyboard, it doesn't work.

Even if I added  `onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) #{usersBean.login()};"`
I tried to add in `<h:form>` and the `<p:keyboard>`. It only work for pressing the physical enter button but not the one in the primefaces keyboard.

Below is the sample of my login page that using the primefaces keyboard:

```
<f:view>
<h:form id="loginForm" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) #{usersBean.login()};">
 <h2><h:outputText value="User Login"/></h2>
 <h:panelGrid columns="2" style=" padding-top: 20px">
         <h:outputLabel value="Email / ID:" for="userIdEmail" />
         <h:inputText id="userIdEmail" value="#{usersBean.userIdEmail}" title="Email / ID" required="true" requiredMessage="The Email / ID field is required." style="width: 200px"/>
         <h:outputLabel value="Password:" for="userPassword" />
         <p:keyboard id="userPassword" value="#{usersBean.loginPassword}" title="UserPassword" showMode="button" password="true" style="width: 195px" />  
</h:panelGrid>
<div>
     <h:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Login" action="#{usersBean.login()}" binding="#{usersBean.loginButton}" style="margin-right: 5px"/>

     <h:message for="loginButton" styleClass="errorStyle" style="text-align: center"/>
</div>
</h:form>
</f:view>
```

Anyone have any idea how to proceed to the login method after pressing the enter button in the primefaces keyboard?

Comment: Did you take a look at the primefaces showcase? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/keyboard.jsf Is this what you want? Submitting a form when you hit enter?

Comment: @Tankhenk if you read the problem and then go to the showcase, you will see that there occurs the same problem.

Comment: Can you please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) of your login code with the `onkeypress` attempt?

Comment: Ahhh i see. You want to submit the form when you hit the enter button of the pf keyboard. My bad didn't read the question well

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thanks for reply. i will post the SSCCE below. This comment have limit space. Do you need the managed bean part too?

Comment: edit your question and add the sscce there

Comment: @Tankhenk ya.. i did go to the showcase and their forum, but they dint give any tutorial or brief regard the enter button in pf keyboard. Even their apidoc also didnt have. btw, thanks for reply too. :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i already edited the question. But it's kinda weird. my enter button at physical keyboard initially doesnt work to submit the form. After added the onkeypress, it works. 
But now even if i remove the onkeypress and recompile or reconnect the glassfish server. my enter button at physical keyboard still work, but the enter button in pf keyboard still not working.

Comment: @BalusC Finally it appear already in the source after add it inside <ui:define>. But it still wont submit the form. After pressing the enter button in pf keyboard, it seem like being refresh.

Comment: @BalusC i have no idea y ur answer post is gone. Please reply me.