# Edit multiline text in p:inputTextarea in p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to edit a multiline text in cells, so I have this code:

```
<p:dataTable ... editable="true" editMode="cell">
    <p:column ...>
         <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{myBean.value}"/></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputTextarea value="#{myBean.value}"/></f:facet>
          </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

But I've faced the problem that I cannot insert new line because changes are sent to backend on enter press. Is it possible to send changes on ctrl+enter or add a small "ok" button?

Comment: If I understand well, you want to change the default keyboard touch to validate an edit on a row?. is it the case?

Comment: What PF version?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919467/how-to-set-an-action-to-primefaces-keyboards-enter-button) it is mentionned `onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) #{usersBean.login()};"` maybe it is related to your situation.

Comment: I have searched further more about `event.keycode`, and I found this : [JSF2 Primefaces Enter key keycode=13 not working with commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919467/how-to-set-an-action-to-primefaces-keyboards-enter-button), read the answer. You may take a look at this too [How to prevent ENTER keypress to submit a web form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585396/how-to-prevent-enter-keypress-to-submit-a-web-form)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28117166/1341535